# Categorification of algebras over fields and rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, soft-question

It seems to me that the categorification of an (unital associative) algebra over a field is that of an algebra object $(A, \mu, \iota)$ in a $\mathbb k$-linear abelian monoidal category $(\mathcal C, 1, \otimes)$ where the tensor product is bilinear on morphisms. Is this missing some critieria, or including some that are not necessary, or completely misunderstood?

And likewise, what would the categorification of an (unital associative) algebra over a commutative ring be? An algebra object $(A, \mu, \iota)$ in a abelian monoidal category?

Comment: It is not what is usually understood by "categorification". You seem to mean "a generalization to this notion to the context of category theory", while usually it means "a higher version of the notion where the object itself becomes a category" (or something like that).

Comment: @CaptainLama Sorry, I'm a little poor when it comes to the language of category theory. Are those the correct criteria for the generalization of the notion of an algebra over a field/ring?

Comment: Well, there are no "correct criteria". It is certainly true that monoid objects in abelian monoidal categories do generalize ordinary algebras, which correspond to working in categories of modules. Whether this is the "correct" generalization will depend on what you want tot do with it.

Comment: I guess what I mean is what the minimal criteria are, even if that might also depend on who you ask

Comment: @nancytrain The issue is: minimal criteria *for what*? For instance, you could remove "abelian" from your conditions, and you would still get a nice generalization of algebras. But it would also contain some examples you might not want to generalize. Or, maybe you need your monoidal category to be cocomplete and closed, or semisimple, or any number of things.

Comment: @KevinArlin Minimal criteria to ensure that nothing weaker than a (in the case of rings) unital associative R-algebra is included, so that we could always see it as a monoid internal to R-mod, by defining it in terms of abelian/monoidal/etc and not defining it as a monoid internal to R-mod. Sorry if my question doesn't make much sense

Comment: @nancytrain Yeah, I'm afraid I don't see why we can't just say "a monoid internal to a monoidal category" then, since nothing weaker than a unital associative $R$-algebra is a monoid internal to $R$-mod. Why add conditions on the category?

Comment: @KevinArlin Because R-mod is not just monoidal but also abelian (among other things). So maybe a better definition would be "a monoid internal to an abelian symmetric monoidal category"

Comment: Once, again, better in what way? $R$-mod is much more than just abelian symmetric monoidal--it's a module category! And that can be stated purely categorically.